# How to grab video frames in Qt?

Tags: c++, image, qt4, video-processing, opticalflow

I am new to Qt, I only know the basics: create interfaces and connect slots. In a few words, my knowledge is not deep at all.

I need to open a video file and capture all of its frames to get the R, G, B channels and, later on, process optical flow (this is already done) frame to frame to finally represent it on a window.

Is it possible to get the video frames with Qt? I have researched a lot but not found anything conclusive.

Comment: Did you check the documentation? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468644/getting-video-frame-in-provided-time-qt/38484477#38484477) may help you to capture frames from a video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why I could not include the necessary Qt headers to process frames (they seemed to always have unresolved dependencies and some did not exist) so I turned to OpenCV 3.0 and did it this way:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(videoFileName);

if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return;

while (cap.isOpened())
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    cv::flip(frame, frame, -1);
    cv::flip(frame, frame, 1);

    // get RGB channels
    w = frame.cols;
    h = frame.rows;
    int size          = w * h * sizeof(unsigned char);
    unsigned char * r = (unsigned char*) malloc(size);
    unsigned char * g = (unsigned char*) malloc(size);
    unsigned char * b = (unsigned char*) malloc(size);

    for(int y = 0; y < h;y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            // get pixel
            cv::Vec3b color = frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(x,y));
            r[y * w + x] = color[2];
            g[y * w + x] = color[1];
            b[y * w + x] = color[0];
        }
    }
}

cap.release();
```

It has worked perfectly for my purpose so I did not continue researching.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [QMediaPlayer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html) to achieve this.

1. Instantiate the [QMediaPlayer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html).
2. Subclass the [QAbstractVideoSurface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html).
3. Set your implementation as the output for the media player via `QMediaPlayer::setVideoOutput`.
4. Feed the media player the needed file and eventually it will start calling `QAbstractVideoSurface::present(const QVideoFrame & frame)` on your implementation of `QAbstractVideoSurface` if the video was loaded successfully. Then you can access the channels and everything from the [QVideoFrame](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html) and draw the frame on a widget.

Comment: I can't find QMediaPlayer anywhere. I've installed Qt via qt-unified-mac-x64-2.0.1-online.dmg but I don't have the mobility package

Comment: @Leo It shouldn't be in the mobility package, just include add `#include <QMediaPlayer>` to your sources and  `QT += multimedia` to your `.pro` file as stated in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html. Also I'm not familiar with the osx versions, but 2.0.1 seems weird - which qt version is it?