# Getting video frame in provided time Qt

Tags: c++, qt, video, qtmultimedia, qt5.7

What I want to do is to get video frame at some time (for example at 20 sec).
I know I could do something like this - rewind video and pause it:

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;
...
player->play();
player->setPosition(20000);
player->pause();
```

But is there some more elegant solution (this seems like a hack to me since I *don't need* whole video but only a frame at some time)?

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800772/how-to-grab-video-frames-in-qt/30863191#30863191) may help you.

Comment: another [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724602/how-to-save-a-frame-using-qmediaplayer) may help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Below steps may help you to capture a frame from a video file.**

Project level

1. QT += multimedia

Code level

1. Initiate QMediaplayer object **(QMediaPlayer(QObject parent, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface)**
2. set QMediaplayer.setVideoOutput to(Subclass of QAbstractVideoSurface)
3. Subclass of QAbstractVideoSurface should re-implement the methods supportedPixelFormats, isFormatSupported, start, **present**
   4.From the **present** method we can get the image buffer of each frame
4. Load the video file using QMediaplayer
5. setMute = true(audio)
6. Set the needed position in milliseconds to the QMediaplayer object
7. Start play method
8. From the **present** method convert the received data buffer to QImage and then to QPixmap(if needed).
9. Once got the pixmap, use it to load in a widget (example: In a QLabel)
10. Immediately pause the video file from playing (if you need to capture some other frame. Other wise stop() instead of pause()). This can be done using signal-slot from subclass's object (QAbstractVideoSurface) to QMediaPlayer object
11. When done,call the stop method of sub class of QAbstractVideoSurface and then the QMediaplayer

Above said example application can be found [here](https://github.com/tryagainworks/StackOverflow/tree/master/QTVideoFrame)

(Application Screen Shot)

[image]

Open Video File : Browse and select a video file
Slider : select the position you want
Capture : capture the image and view in a QLabel
Save : Save the captured image

Comment: how to play video in this case properly, I captured frame but wasn't to play video file. Can you help?